# Netbeans debug jdk

Tags: debugging, netbeans

During debugging, i need to inspect variables inside JDK, say the class of a swing control like JTextField, JEditorPane, or whatsoever. 
The debugger steps into these classes code, but when moving the mouse pointer over a local variable, it gives the message "**xxx is not a known variable in the current context**".
I've certainly a wrong debugging-configuration entry, but I don't guess which one :-).

(My NetBeans version is 6.9 but probably this issue is not version-related)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRE classes are compiled with debugging info off therefore you won't see any local variables while stepping through the source. This is done for performance/size reasons but you *can* recompile the JRE classes if you need to see the local variables while debugging.

See [this thread](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103334.html) on Javalobby for info on recompiling the JRE classes with debug info included.

**Follow Up:** One way to use your alternative JDK is to make a copy of your "regular" JDK and put the modified rt.jar inside the copy, then you can add a Java Platform to NetBeans and use the modified JDK for development. To add another Java Platform to NetBeans, click `Tools > Java Platforms` menu item then click the `Add Platform...` button and browse to your modified JDK folder and give it a name like `JDK 6 With Debug Symbols`.

You will need to change the Java Platform that your project uses by right clicking your project and choose `Properties > Libraries` then use the `Java Platform` combo box to choose your modified JDK.

Comment: Ok, have you a smart idea about how to add the new rtWithDebug.jar to NetBeans?

Comment: thanks. however i'm stuck with sources compilation, i've opened this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226009/compile-jdk-via-ant .Actually src.zip doesn't contain all the needed classes and I end up with a rt_with_symbols.jar that depends on rt.jar... I'm at the point of trying this jdk platform but I think it wont work.