# compile jdk via ant

Tags: ant, compiler-errors, java

I want to compile jdk files in order to include debug infromation.
I'd like to use ant, because it's included in my NetBeans environement, so i've done the following:

1. unzipped /src.zip in a tmp directory
2. created a very simple build.xml file (one default target, one taks) in my tmp directory:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="CompileJDK" default="default" basedir=".">
    <target name="default">
    <javac srcdir="."
             destdir="jdkwd"
             debug="on"
    />
    </target>
    </project>
```

1. created a jdkwd directory
2. launched ant without parameters (just >log.txt)

This leads to 100 compilation errors such as:

```
    [javac] C:\jdkdebug\java\awt\Window.java:196: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class IdentityArrayList
[javac] location: class java.awt.Window
[javac]     private static final IdentityArrayList<Window> allWindows = new IdentityArrayList<Window>();
```

I have just one JDK installed on my machine, so i don't know why it does not resolve all this references.

UPDATE:
The majority of these unresolved references belongs to the package:

```
sun.awt.util
```

The question now is corrected to: where are the missing jdk files?

Comment: ok, i've put a bounty and now it is expiring. Many answers point out that the process isn't "easy" and maybe those sources aren't supposed to be compiled, and are not provided to do that. Since there isn't a single, positive answer, I let half the bounty to be automatically assigned to the most voted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building the JDK itself is a complex process and is not achievable by a simple `javac` call wrapped inside an `ant` project.

You should look at the [OpenJDK Build README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html) to get instructions on how to build for your platform.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-141681.html

> #### A14. Where can I get the Java programming language source code?
>
> Java Software has two separate bundles of source code that you can obtain at no charge:
>
> The Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition itself contains a file called src.zip that contains the source code for the public classes in the java package. **Because this does not contain sun.* classes, you cannot do a complete build of the Java technology from these source files.** These source files are for your information, to supplement the documentation, so you can see how Java technology works.
>
> The full source code release is available from us by going to the Community Source Code Licensing web site..

The community source code link is incorrect: it's now http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a [classpath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) to your javac call.

```
<classpath path="/PATH/to/missing_class/" />
```

Also, try running ant with the -d and -v options. It's a lot of output but will show you where its searching for classes.

Comment: Well, going through these errors, i've discovered that my sources completely misses the sun.* package. The symbol above refers to sun.awt.util.IdentityArrayList. How could this happen?

Comment: @AgostinoX AFAIK they don't provide sources for many (any?) internal packages.

Comment: I think that the Sun classes are not part of the standard. What JVM are you using?

Comment: i use hotspot 1.6, but jdk isn't supposed to be independent from jvm? @dave: but when i debug with netbeans i see those sources!

Comment: The sun classes are part of the JVM. Did you add the rt.jar to the class path?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this post](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103334.html) (from 2007), you should include rt.jar and tools.jar on your classpath to compile the JRE sources.

However, I tried that, and it doesn't work for me (100 errors).

There are more elaborate and older (2004) instructions in christhielen's post in the [Java bug requesting debug symbols](http://www.java.net/external?url=https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4652184).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Gentoo compiling OpenJDK would be as simple as running `emerge dev-java/icedtea`.

There is a `debug` use flag that would switch off all optimizations, I haven't tried it myself but chances are that this is what you want. If it's not - then it should not be a big deal to change build scripts, but would require you to learn a little bit of portage.